# Updating scope after adding permission to multi-tennant app

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to add an integration for One Drive to an app that I've already integrated with Outlook.

The problem is that after adding Files.ReadWrite.All and granting permissions in both App Registration and Enterprise Application, it doesn't appear in the scope of the access token, so the token isn't being updated with the new permission.

Not sure if it's important, but Calendars.ReadWrite (for Outlook) appears in both Admin & User consent in the Enterprise App, while Files.ReadWrite.All only appears in Admin consent. They're both present in the App Registration.

Any ideas?

These are the permissions:

[image]

And this is the token response:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot of your permission granted to the application and a screenshot of the parsing token.

Comment: @CarlZhao I've added the screenshots you asked for.

Comment: Okay, wait a minute. Let me test it.

Comment: After my test, it does appear in my access token. You need to confirm that your token is obtained by the application that you granted permission to. Check the appid in the token to make sure it matches the application in Azure ad. If the application id is the same, try to request an access token again and parse it.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCTWI.png

Comment: @CarlZhao thanks. I see that you also added profile, openid & email permissions. Maybe they need to be added as well. I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Hi. Have you tested it? How is the result?

Comment: @CarlZhao I just finished checking, and it worked! Thank you for your help!

Comment: So happy for you, I moved the comment to the answer, and you can accept it to end the thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment moved to answer：

After my test, it does appear in my access token.You need to confirm that your token is obtained by the application that you granted permission to. Check the **appid** in the token to make sure it matches the application in Azure ad. If the application id is the same, try to request an access token again and parse it.